# C言語のqsortについて

Tags: c

C言語についての質問です。

`qsort` の課題にて、下記のコードを提出したところ、

```
printf("a or d: ");
scanf(" %c", &ad);
qsort(sin, 9, sizeof(int), ad == 'a'?cmp_u:cmp_d);
```

`'a'?cmp_u:cmp_d);` と一行にまとめるのではなく、`if` 文を使用して分けて書くように言われて下記の様にコードを書き直したのですが、エラーになってしまいます…
どなたか書き方を教えて頂けないでしょうか？

```
if (ad == 'a')
        qsort(sin, 9, cmp_u);
    else
        qsort(sin, 9, cmp_d);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> qsort(sin, 9, sizeof(int), ad == 'a'?cmp_u:cmp_d);

コレ↑を，例えば `cmp_u` を使うように書き換えるなら

`qsort(sin, 9, sizeof(int), cmp_u );  //最後の引数を除いては同じ`

とすべきではあるまいか．
（あなたの記述だと引数が３個になってしまっている）

Comment: ありがとうございます。